# Force Meteor Autoform to revalidate when input value is changed programmatically

Tags: forms, validation, meteor

I'm using Meteor Autoform.

*Demo site, liable to disappear at any time:* http://exmp-eat-46040.euw1.nitrousbox.com/form

I have a Postcode/Address Form with a `<SELECT>` giving street addresses that the user can select.
I have other `<INPUT>`s for House Number, Street Name, City etc.

When the user selects their address from the `<SELECT>` I use jQuery to poke the address details into the various `<INPUT>`s

When the user doesn't select an address I clear down all the inputs:

```
Template.addressSelect.events({
  'change #addressSelect': function(e) {
      if ($(e.target).val()=='none') {
        // no address slected, clear the other fields
        $('input[name="curflat_name"]').val('');
        $('input[name="curhouse_name"]').val('');
        $('input[name="curhouse_no"]').val('');
        $('input[name="curstreet_name"]').val('');
        $('input[name="curcounty"]').val('');
        $('input[name="curtown"]').val('');
        $('input[name="curcity"]').val('');
     }
  } // change #addressSelect
```

});

**Scenario**

1. The user DOESN'T select any Address and they click my form's *Submit*
   button.
2. Autoform displays error messages for the missing required
   fields.
3. The user selects an Address and I populate the `<INPUT>`s
4. The error messages are still shown

**Question**

How do I clear down any Autoform generated Validation Errors? Or how do I trigger Autoform to run it's form validation after I have poked good data into the form fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick solution would be to trigger the change event after changing the value of the input. `.val("").trigger("change")`. This is good practise anyways, as other scripts won't notice the change otherwise too.

Answer (score 0):

This way?

```
AutoForm.resetForm(formId)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using 0.8.1.1 and the autoform docs say "There is no AutoForm instance.". I've tried your suggestion but without success.